# Frame rate drop when SKProductsRequestDelegate – productsRequest:didReceiveResponse is called

Tags: ios, multithreading, storekit

I've noticed that there's a frame rate drop (presumably caused by a cpu spike) when [SKProductsRequestDelegate  productsRequest:didReceiveResponse] is called. Is there any way to avoid this? Can I get the SKProductsRequest stuff to run on a lower-priority thread?